# Javascript - Object reference returning null even though it shoudn't

Tags: javascript, dom, null

I've got this:

```
var strBox = document.getElementById("txtSTR");
var strModBox = document.getElementById("txtSTRMod");
var refBox = document.getElementById("txtREF");
var refModBox = document.getElementById("txtREFMod");
var fortBox = document.getElementById("txtFOR");
var forModBox = document.getElementById("txtFORMod");
var intBox = document.getElementById("txtINT");
var intModBox = document.getElementById("txtINTMod");
```

These vars all point to text boxes (read only) in my HTML document.

They rely on populating their .value with the following array:

```
//0-STR, 1-REF, 2-FOR, 3-INT, 4-JUD, 5-CHA, 6-WIL, 7-TOU
var charAttsAR = ["8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8"];
```

They are populated with the relevant array entry manually from a function called popDefDat() like this:

```
strBox.value = charAttsAR[0];
strModBox.value = modSetter(charAttsAR[0]);

refBox.value = charAttsAR[1];
refModBox.value = modSetter(charAttsAR[1]);

fortBox.value = charAttsAR[2];
forModBox.value = modSetter(charAttsAR[2]);

intBox.value = charAttsAR[3];
intModBox.value = modSetter(charAttsAR[3]);
```

....and so on

My issue is that strBox, strModBox, refBox and refModBox all initialise their data fine. However, at fortBox, it throws "fortBox is null" and I have no idea why. The code is identical, I have my script loaded just before the end of my  tag and I also have:

```
//initialise default data when page loads
window.onload = popDefDat()
```

Honestly, I'm stuck. Any advice appreciated.

Here's the html too:

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" onsubmit="return false" action="">    
<p><label></label>&nbsp;
<label for="lblHeadATT"></label>

<input name="lblHeadATT" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="lblHeadATT" value="Points" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="lbHeadMOD"></label>

<input name="lbHeadMOD" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="lbHeadMOD" value="Mod" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="txtPointBuy"></label>

<input name="txtPointBuy" type="text" id="txtPointBuy" readonly="readonly" />
```

```
<p>Strength: 
<label for="txtSTR"></label>
<input name="txtSTR" type="text" id="txtSTR" readonly="readonly" />
<label for="txtSTRMod"></label>
<input name="txtSTRMod" type="text" id="txtSTRMod" readonly="readonly" /> 

<input type="button" name="Btn_StrMinus" id="Btn_StrMinus" value="-" onclick="FNCstrSub()" />

<input type="button" name="Btn_StrPlus" id="Btn_StrPlus" value="+" onclick="FNCstrPlus()"/>
```

```
<p>Reflex:
<label for="txtREF"></label>
<input name="txtREF" type="text" id="txtREF" readonly="readonly" />
<label for="txtREFMod"></label>
<input name="txtREFMod" type="text" id="txtREFMod" readonly="readonly" />

<input type="button" name="Btn_RefMinus" id="Btn_RefMinus" value="-" onclick="FNCrefSub()" />

<input type="button" name="Btn_RefPlus" id="Btn_RefPlus" value="+" onclick="FNCrefPlus()"/>
```

```
<p>Fortitude: 
<label for="txtREF"></label>
<input name="txtFOR" type="text" id="txtREF" readonly="readonly" />
<label for="txtFORMod"></label>
<input name="txtFORMod" type="text" id="txtFORMod" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" name="Btn_ForMinus" id="Btn_ForMinus" value="-" onclick="FNCforSub()" />
<input type="button" name="Btn_ForPlus" id="Btn_ForPlus" value="+" onclick="FNCforPlus()"/>
</p>

<p>Intellect: 
<label for="txtINT"></label>
<input name="txtINT" type="text" id="txtINT" readonly="readonly" />
<label for="txtINTMod"></label>
<input name="txtINTMod" type="text" id="txtINTMod" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="submit" name="Btn_IntMinus" id="Btn_IntMinus" value="-" onclick="FNCintSub()"/>
<input type="submit" name="Btn_IntPlus" id="Btn_IntPlus" value="+"onclick="FNCintPlus()" />
```

I've yet to write the tags for the other text boxes and buttons as I was hoping to solve this before carrying on.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have any `id="txtFOR"` inputs.  You have `name="txtFOR" id="txtREF"`

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtFOR")` - Where in your code do you have an element with that `id`?  Which element do you expect that to find?  *Why*?

Comment: pro tip: whenever you repeat the same line more than two times, you should put it into a function / use a loop / use an array.

Comment: You need to change <input name="txtFOR" type="text" id="txtREF" readonly="readonly" /> to <input name="txtFOR" type="text" id="txtFOR" readonly="readonly" />